# SQL query to get children of entity into same row as parent entity

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has the following fields:

```
| entity_id | parent_entity_id | name | status |
|----------------------------------------------|
```

I'm attempting to write a query that displays every entity that doesn't have a parent and displays their children's name and status inline for a result like this:

```
| entity_id | name | child_entity_1_name | child_entity_1_status |...| child_entity_4_name | child_entity_4_status |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I know the data is structured so that every entity has at least 3 children, but not every entity has 4 (therefore the ones with 3 will have NULL in the columns for the 4th child name and status). Furthermore, I know that no entity that has a parent is a parent itself.

From the introductory database classes I've taken, this seems like a complicated query. The part that's tripping me up is getting all of the sub-entities into the same row. I can get one sub-entity in the same row as its parent but can't get more than one.

EDIT: The database is basically a set of trees each with a height of 2. There are no grandparents.

```
PARENT_ENT_1                       PARENT_ENT_2
|  |   |   |                       |  |   |  |
|  |   |   |                       |  |   |  |
C1 C2  C3  C4                      C5 C6  C7 C8
```

Every row in my result query should represent one of these trees

Comment: If you do not need them in separate fields, using `GROUP_CONCAT()` could make it a relatively simple query.

Comment: I do need them in separate fields unfortunately

Comment: It would be much easier to run a simple join query and format the data in another language.

Comment: I posted an answer that should/might work; but I'd second what Paul just said and say it sounds more a problem for the application layer/language to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1127f/27/0

But I feel like it should be much, much easier.

I basically had this:

```
SELECT P.entity_id as Parent_id, P.name as Parent_Name, C1.entity_id, C1.Name, 
       C2.entity_id, C2.Name, C3.entity_id, C4.Name, C4.entity_id, C4.Name
FROM entity P
JOIN entity C1 on C1.parent_entity_id = P.entity_id
JOIN entity C2 on C2.parent_entity_id = P.entity_id
JOIN entity C3 on C3.parent_entity_id = P.entity_id
LEFT JOIN entity C4 on C4.parent_entity_id = P.entity_id
WHERE P.parent_entity_id IS NULL
AND C1.entity_id < C2.entity_id
AND C2.entity_id < C3.entity_id
AND C3.entity_id < C4.entity_id
```

But of course that final join won't work as it is there, because the `WHERE` clause turns it into an `INNER` join..  Maybe someone will see an easy way to handle that part.

I ended up relenting and using a `UNION`, one half for parents with 3 children and the other for parents with 4.

**Edit: Thank you Paul for making the final join work!**

```
SELECT P.entity_id as Parent_id, P.name as Parent_Name, C1.entity_id, c1.Name, 
       C2.entity_id, c2.Name, C3.entity_id, c3.Name, C4.entity_id, c4.Name
FROM entity P
JOIN entity C1 on C1.parent_entity_id = P.entity_id
JOIN entity C2 on C2.parent_entity_id = P.entity_id
JOIN entity C3 on C3.parent_entity_id = P.entity_id
LEFT JOIN entity C4 on C4.parent_entity_id = P.entity_id
                   and c3.entity_id < c4.entity_id
WHERE p.parent_entity_id IS NULL
AND C1.entity_id < C2.entity_id
AND C2.entity_id < C3.entity_id
AND (3 = (SELECT COUNT(1)
          FROM entity c
          WHERE c.parent_entity_id = p.entity_id)
     OR c4.entity_id is not null)
```

Comment: You need to move the last condition `c3.entity_id < c4.entity_id` to the ON clause of the LEFT JOIN.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I thought that too but it doesn't work.  Here is a better fiddle to mess with, easier to see the conundrum: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1127f/28/0

Comment: Aha! @PaulSpiegel nicely done.  I kept trying to write a `CASE` to accomplish that but my brain wasn't cooperating.

Comment: This is incredibly done, I was skeptical that I could even do this only using SQL, much less using a query this succinct. Thank you much @PaulSpiegel and Aaron!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a query for two children:

```
select
    p.entity_id, p.name,
    c1.name   as child_entity_1_name,
    c1.status as child_entity_1_status,
    c2.name   as child_entity_2_name,
    c2.status as child_entity_2_status
from entities p
left join entities c1 on c1.entity_id = (
    select c.entity_id
    from entities c
    where c.parent_entity_id = p.entity_id
    order by c.entity_id asc
    limit 1
    offset 0
)
left join entities c2 on c2.entity_id = (
    select c.entity_id
    from entities c
    where c.parent_entity_id = p.entity_id
    order by c.entity_id asc
    limit 1
    offset 1
)
where p.parent_entity_id is null
```

For `child_entity_3` you will use `offset 2` and for `child_entity_4` you will use `offset 3`.

But I would rather just use the following two queries

```
select p.entity_id, p.name
from entities p
where p.parent_entity_id is null;

select p.entity_id as parent_id, c.name, c.status
from entities p
join entities c on c.parent_entity_id = p.entity_id
where p.parent_entity_id is null
order by p.entity_id, c.entity_id;
```

and create the desired table in application language with a couple of simple loops.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit messy, and there's probably a better means of storing this, especially because this is only manually scalable.

Assuming a table:

```
CREATE TABLE
parents
(
    entity_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    parent_entity_id INT,
    name VARCHAR(15),
    `status` VARCHAR(15)
);
```

**EDITED**

With some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO
 `parents`
(entity_id, parent_entity_id, name, `status`)
VALUES
(1, NULL, 'Parent1', 'sfsd'),
(2, 1, 'Child1A', 'sfsd'),
(3, 1, 'Child1B', 'sfsd'),
(4, 1, 'Child1C', 'sfsd'),
(5, NULL, 'Parent2', 'sfsd'),
(6, 5, 'Child2A', 'sfsd'),
(7, 5, 'Child2B', 'sfsd');
```

You can create a view, temporary table or permanent table (depending on your ultimate goal) that stores the following:

```
SET @row_number = 0;
SET @parent_id = 0;

SELECT
  @row_number:=CASE
        WHEN @parent_id = parent_entity_id THEN @row_number + 1
        ELSE 1
  END AS `child_num`,
  entity_id,
  @parent_id:= parent_entity_id as parent_entity_id,
  name,
  `status`
FROM
  `parents`
WHERE
  `parent_entity_id` IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
  parent_entity_id ASC,
  entity_id ASC;
```

The above would be easier with SQL Server and using `PARTITION BY` and `ROW_NUMBER`, but this is a way around it.

Gives us:
[image]

Then, you could join that table/view 3 times, adding a second `JOIN` condition for the child number. This is demoed here, using a derived table due to the restrictions in SQL Fiddle with data modification, which I supposed could be done all 3 times, though you'd have to look into the efficiency and benchmarking.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ddef3/3

Ultimately, it gives us:

[image]

Comment: I was considering this as an answer too; but they'll run into the problem of getting parent 1 with children 1, 2, 3; and with children 1, 3, 2; and 2, 1, 3 and so on...and joining with c1.id < c2.id etc still ends up with 1, 2, 3/ 2, 3, null/ etc... *The solution may need one or more subqueries to establish an order.*

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, the children all share the same parent, and there are no grandparents

Comment: Okay, then I need to rethink this... but @Uueerdo seems to have a good start

Comment: @littlespice3, updated my answer after some thinking last night

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @cNum := 0;
SET @prevParent := 0;

SELECT p.id, p.Name
   , GROUP_CONCAT(IF(numberedChildren.childNum = 1, c.Name, NULL)) AS child_entity_1_name 
   , GROUP_CONCAT(IF(numberedChildren.childNum = 1, c.Status, NULL)) AS child_entity_1_status 
   , GROUP_CONCAT(IF(numberedChildren.childNum = 2, c.Name, NULL)) AS child_entity_2_name 
   , GROUP_CONCAT(IF(numberedChildren.childNum = 2, c.Status, NULL)) AS child_entity_2_status 
   , ...
FROM (
   SELECT @cNum := IF(@prevParent <> orderedChildren.parent_id, @cNum + 1, 1) AS childNum
      , orderedChildren.id AS child_id
      , @prevParent := orderedChildren.parent_id AS parent_id
   FROM (
      SELECT parent_id, id
      FROM sometable
      ORDER BY parent_id, id
   ) AS orderedChildren
) AS numberedChildren
INNER JOIN sometable AS p ON numberedChildren.parent_id = p.id
INNER JOIN sometable AS c ON numberedChildren.child_id = c.id
GROUP BY p.id, p.Name
;
```

I *think* this script might work. It relies on `GROUP_CONCAT`, and pretty much any other aggregate function, ignoring null values.

You can probably also make it a single query (dropping the initial SET statements) by changing this line:

`) AS orderedChildren`

to

`) AS orderedChildren, (SELECT @cNum AS cnInit, @prevParent AS ppInit) As init`

but that is not my usual style for session variable init.

Edit: Also, ordered children may not NEED to be a subquery (you might be able to do the ORDER BY and childNum calculation in the same subquery) but such use of session variables can be...delicate.

Comment: This is very eye opening and I'll look into it for a bit, but where is GROUP_CONCAT closed? Every line in the query there isn't a closing )

Edit: or maybe it's the IF that's missing the closing )

Comment: @littlespice3 good catch; the `)`'s were forgotten, not intentionally omitted; I've corrected it.

Comment: @littlespice3 This is why you should provide the CREATE and INSERT statements with sample data or a fiddle link, so one can easily test the solution. Help other to write their answers and you will get better answers.

Comment: @littlespice3 Not sure if it is important, but it's worth mentioning that my answer will omit entities that are neither children nor parents.